# The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm getting the following error when using a compiled code from Typescript to Javascript when using Next

`The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"`

Could someone help me?

Comment: I guess there is not enough information to help you, it would be great if you shared an example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share your tsconfig.json so that we can take a look at it and see whats the config given there.

Comment: Uploaded [tsconfig.json](https://gist.github.com/PsykoSoldi3r/60060a84d8cb6b18911771f0dbff87f0) file to gist

Answer (score -1):

The following config can be used:

```
{"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "esnext"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi regretwary. Please consider adding an explanation.